# Deserialize object without knowing its type in Java

Tags: java, serialization

Normally the deserialization is done in the following way:

```
PersistentTime time = null;
time = (PersistentTime)ois.readObject();
```

where ois is ObjectInputStream object and PersistentTime is the class we want to deserialize to.

So if my application has 2 or 3 kinds of objects being sent over the network, is it possible to deserialize the object without knowing the type or know the type of object first and deserialize later according to that type?

Comment: There are several self-describing serialization formats out there (e.g. Protocol Buffers or Thrift), but you'll probably need some sort of reflection in your program to do anything useful with the resulting object. After all, you don't know what type of object you have

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course; you're doing that already! But if you want to save the typecast for later:

```
Object deserialized = ois.readObject();

if (deserialized instanceof PersistentTime) {
  PersistentTime time = (PersistentTime)deserialized;
  // do something with time...
} else if (deserialized instanceof SomethingElse) {
  ...
} else if (...) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Deserialize it then check its type

```
Object object = ois.readObject();
if (object instanceof PersistentTime) {
    PersistentTime time = (PersistentTime)object;
    // Do something to PersistentTime
} else if (object instanceof SomeClass) {
    // Do something to someclass
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first read the object, then check its type, then cast to appropriate type and use, e.g.

```
Object obj = ois.readObject();

if (obj instanceof PersistentTime) {
    PersistentTime time =- (PersistentTime)obj;
    // use time
}
```